# Can you identify these items?

Tags: equipment

Is anyone able to tell me what these are?

The openings are tapered as though whatever is placed in them is meant to be easy to remove.  They don't look like the shape of anything I can think of, especially the semi-circles.  I don't think they are pastry cutters, they are too thick and would be made of metal, plus...the shapes.  I doubt they are molds, they wouldn't have an open bottom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not crazy about the dumpling mold answer, but if you can give us a measurement or sense of scale, that might help.

Comment: Why? They look like dumpling molds to me.

Comment: @FuzzyChef it is certainly possible, though I was leaning more toward extrusion dies.  That is why some sense of size would be helpful.

Comment: Moscafj: you wouldn't have those cutting edges around the shapes on extrusion plates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh...wait...I should have thought of a reverse image search.

It seems they are dumpling molds.  https://rotanya.com/product/magic-dumpling-model/

Answer (score 3):

They are, in fact, dumpling press trays. Here is an exact match

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me they look like they could be applied to the other end of a (piston) potato masher in order to obtain thicker or star shaped sticks of dough, for example for churros or for Italian "passatelli".

Answer (score 0):

The design and angle of the rim suggests they are attachments for extruding. If they were molds, they'd have little 'legs' like in molds in the magic dumpling model pictures your reverse image searched. So I agree with @DavidP